# How do you pass query string parameters to the new HTTP API Beta?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to use the new AWS API Gateway HTTP API service that is in beta. I have been able to get simple requests to work with static paths or with path parameters, but have not been able to figure out how to add query string parameters. I see that I should be able to access these through the event['queryStringParameters'] array, but I can't add the parameters to the route. When I attempt to send a request with query parameters, I get a 404.

Because of how new this beta is, the AWS docs aren't complete and don't cover this. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I just had a typo my path, you can just add query string parameters to your request and access them from the event['queryStringParameters'] array.